# The easiest way to play an audio RTMP stream in Android

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I found some Android RTMP libraries (like this : http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/).

The problem is that there is no accurate documentation on how we can use it.

In my case, I have a simple RTMP live audio stream (ex: rtmp://myserver/myapp/myliveaudio).

What is the easiest way to read it in my Android app?

Please, I don't want links: I need some pieces of code or some accurate step-by-step explanation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello, have done Rtmp Streaming? can you help me please? i want play Rtmp streaming in my app..

Comment: me too same,,,, please share how to do live streaming with rtmp.

Comment: Well, I chose it as the best answer and not THE answer. In fact, I did it in another way : I used Flex Mobile. It's very easy. But, the "problem" is that the user has to install the Air Runtime. So, I have no clean solution for instance.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 11):

It is unfortunately non-trivially difficult to do. Right now your best bet is to look at the code in http://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/: specifically look at http://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/source/browse/trunk/example/com/ryong21/example/recorder/RecorderClient.java and http://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/source/browse/trunk/example/com/ryong21/example/recorder/Recorder.java. These walk through taking in a streamed MP3 file and recording its contents to an FLV file on disk.

You would need to modify the RecorderClient.java file (specifically around line 193) to play the audio data out the speakers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did read the code. But as I mentioned it, I'm trying to play a live stream. So imagine if I create a local file to bufferize the 12 hours incoming stream!

Comment: You couldn't buffer it: you would have to feed the actual data obtained from `IoBuffer data = ((IStreamData) rtmpEvent).getData().asReadOnlyBuffer();` into a suitable decoder that would generate raw audio samples you can feed into an `AudioTrack`.

Comment: I am surprised that Android API doesn't directly support playing RTMP streams. This answer seems to make sense. I am going to give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this helps, but... I was able to do something similar (rtmp - streaming video) using Flash, so you need Android 2.2+ for this.

Anyway, I just wrote an HTML page displaying the flash video then opened the page in a WebView.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html, body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        height:100%;
    }
    #altContent{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
</style>
<title>YOUR TITLE HERE!</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};

    flashvars.HaloColor = "0x0086db";
    flashvars.ToolTips = "true";
    flashvars.AutoPlay = "true";
    flashvars.VolumeLevel = "50";
    flashvars.CaptionURL = "YOUR CAPTION HERE";
    flashvars.Title = "YOUR TITLE HERE";
    flashvars.Logo = "";
    flashvars.SRC = "rtmp://YOUR STREAM URL HERE";
    flashvars.BufferTime = "5";
    flashvars.AutoHideControls = "false";
    flashvars.IsLive = "true";

    var params = {};
    params.wmode = "transparent";
    params.allowfullscreen = "true";

    var attributes = {};
    attributes.id = "L3MP";

    swfobject.embedSWF("http://media-player.cdn.level3.net/flash/v1_1_1/Level3MediaPlayer.swf", "altContent", "100%", "100%", "10.1.0","http://media-player.cdn.level3.net/flash/v1_1_1/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="altContent">
   <center> <BR><BR><span style="color:red"><b>Please Install Adobe Flash Player</b>  
        </span><BR><BR>
  <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img     src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a>
  </center>    
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
</script>
</html>
```

OK... now just save that in your assets folder in your project
and open it with something like this in your activity :

```
    String LocalFile = "file:///android_asset/YOUR_HTML_FILE.htm";

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_WEB_VIEW);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);

    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true); 
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.loadUrl(LocalFile);
```

Its a bit of a work around... Hope it works for you. CDub.

Comment: hi, i tried the same code you place over here, but i am not able to see anything. When i start my app, app starts than it will stay visible for 3-4 seconds (blank activity with black screen) and than it closes without any exception. It also not showing any exception in DDMS. Can you suggest me any solution ? i really need this.

Comment: hello, i had try this, but it not work and facing some problem so can you help me please..?

Comment: I'm trying to use workaround but It's not playing the stream. I have installed flash player on SDK but it says that flash is not installed!

Comment: Thanks for that share. Well, I was able to make it work using Flex Mobile which comes with a nice set of out-of-box features like reading/sending rtmp streams. But, I still want a pluginless Android solution for that question. Thanks again.