# Rtmp Video Streaming using WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am working on rtmp streaming using WebView. I am using this code given on this link [The easiest way to play an audio RTMP stream in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349714/the-easiest-way-to-play-an-audio-rtmp-stream-in-android) by Club. I copied this code in phonegap but it is not working. Can anybody help me in this.

Second thing I want to know is what is  CaptionURL in this code. What we write in it?
Because I have this kind of rtmp link.rtmp://62.220.181.209/oflaDemo/avatar-vp6.flv to play.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the code in following url:
http://code.google.com/p/android-recorder/downloads/detail?name=android-rtmp-player_src.zip&can=2&q=**.It worked for me.