# How to Play RTMP Live Streaming url in android

Tags: android

I am trying to play rtmp live streaming url in android how can do this.i know about rtsp.but how can i do with rtmp.

Comment: Check this link for accurate solution for RMTP Live Streaming http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349714/the-easiest-way-to-play-an-audio-rtmp-stream-in-android Works for me

Answer (score 1):

Play using any flash player like flowplayer. You can do the setup of the player from http://flowplayer.org. `rtmp` stream is default flash and you will need any flash to play the stream if you dont want to use rtsp.

Comment: Thank for rply, i want to use RTMP only, i had try using different way   and i also used RTMP client Lib but no result,. this is my Url for Stream "rtmp://fml.6329.edgecastcdn.net/206329/SikhChannel" is it ok or it miss somthing for streaming , can you tell me please? if you have code for this streaming can you send me please?

Comment: If you are trying to play it directly in the browser it will not play in any way you do

Comment: I am playing rtmp video url using flowplayer in android. It is playing good. You will need to define the `netconnectionurl` and the format supported by android. You can check the link for rtmp streaming http://support.netdna.com/knowledgebase/rtmp/ for reference

Comment: @user850234 - does the flowplayer get integrated into the application itself? or how ?? could you please assist?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille - The flowplayer gets integrated into the application itself. Basically you embed the player into your code. For the player to work into your browser, you will need the flash plugin installed. Does this address your question, or you are looking for something else.

Comment: yes it sure does. That means i would need the flash player plugin and this would open in a webview sort of thing correct?

Comment: yes, thats how it works. Without installing flash plugin flowplayer would not start in your web browser.