# How to play rtmp video in videoview in android?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, rtmp

I want to play rtmp video in videoview , so how i can play rtmp video in my app?

```
String host = "rtmp://example.com";
String fileName = "www.mp4";
int port = 1935;

Connection string rtmp://example/cfx/st
```

How i can play video ?

Regards,
girish

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Flash (at least for devices with 2.2+ android and Flash-supported CPUs)

- http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?13087-Android-RTMP-Live-Streaming
- [The easiest way to play an audio RTMP stream in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349714/the-easiest-way-to-play-an-audio-rtmp-stream-in-android)