# Playing RTMP stream in Android using flash and WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, flash, rtmp

I'm trying to use the solution introduced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7142295/370073). Everything is ok and the page loads w/out any problem. The only catch is here that it says Flash Player is not installed, while it is.
I'm working inside SDK. Is there a problem using Flash Based content in SDK? My API level is 10 (2.3.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these 2 lines :

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

that should make it work I already got it working in my app :)

Also make sure you have the right version of flash player installed for your device.