# Play audio RTMP stream on android

Tags: android, audio, streaming, audio-streaming, rtmp

Has anyone had any success playing back an audio RTMP stream on Android using http://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client or know of any other non-flash solutions. The example that comes with the android rtmp source records the audio to a file but I'm looking for example code that plays back over speakers (or bluetooth).

[The easiest way to play an audio RTMP stream in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349714/the-easiest-way-to-play-an-audio-rtmp-stream-in-android) has a partial discussion of what's needed.