# RTMP audio live streaming on Android

Tags: android, audio, unity-game-engine, rtmp

I need an Android audio streaming player that I could use to play live RTMP streams?  I have been searching extensively and have not yet found one that I am comfortable using.  I have looked at Vitamio (https://www.vitamio.org/en/) and have tried contacting them for purchasing their source, but have received no response after about two weeks.  Therefore, I need to find a different vendor.

Here are the basic requirements:

1. Audio only playback
2. No hosting services necessary - I already have RTMP streams.
3. Android
4. Intended to be used as a plugin for a Unity 3D project.

Comment: If you consider Flash a viable solution then look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349714/the-easiest-way-to-play-an-audio-rtmp-stream-in-android)

Comment: We don't consider Flash a viable solution because we don't want to run Flash in our app.  Our Android app is intended to be used as a plugin for a Unity 3D project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [libVLC](https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample)?

You can also use my pre-built binaries from Bintray:

[armeabi-v7a](https://bintray.com/tomasvalenta/maven/libVLC-android/view)

[x86](https://bintray.com/tomasvalenta/maven/libVLC-x86-android/view)